# why is localhost:3000 not working right away but loads if I sit there and wait

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, localhost

[picture of error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a7aH.png)

Anyone know how I can fix this?  I just created a new React project with npx create-react-app, and when I try to enter npm start, this is what I see in the browser when it goes to localhost:3000.  But if I go to 127.0.0.1:3000, it works right away. Now, if I wait 5 minutes, it finally does load the react app automatically if I stare at localhost:3000.  I'm confused about why it's not working right away when I go to localhost:3000, but it'll eventually load after like 5 minutes.  I've tried disabling my firewall and a few other things, I'm just confused about why it doesn't load up in Chrome right away from localhost:3000.

I disabled my firewall/anti-virus.  I've tried flushdns.

Comment: Are you getting any configuration error while run project in terminal ?

Comment: Yes, the error I'm getting in the console is crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the cache inside the browser?

Comment: Yes, I've tried deleting the cache from inside the browser, and that did not work

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be in the comment section